# Level-crossing and statistical moment

Tags: moments

I recall that I read some time ago that the count of level crossings of a signal in a period of time is equivalent or proportional to a statistical moment for that signal (cannot recall the particular distribution) but I don't remember which moment (central or otherwise) and how to prove it. Does this ring a bell to anyone?

Comment: Did you try Googling on something along the lines of "level crossing" signal "statistical moment"?